# How to stop a push with compile mistakes?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, server, devops, githooks

I recently pushed a code error (Javascript-Used a const instead of a let) to a server and the admin say that it stopped other developers pushing their code? On other sites/employments i'm sure I have done this once before but it was just reporting "build failed" in the log file and the update was rejected.

On this occasion the server did not update (As it had not been doing anyway) but subsequent pushes by other developers did not update.

The fact that the server was not updating before I pushed (As other developers reported) shows me that my syntax error did not cause the problem of the server not updating with pushed code.

Help! they are blaming me for a problem that was on the server for a whole week before my 'syntax error' push!

Any replies by other developers and AWS DevOps would be greatfully recieved..

Isn't it usual for there to be server hook code in place so that the pushed code is rejected and does not cause damage to a server application?

Comment: Yes. Your CI/CD pipeline should start out trying to build the code you checked in, then perform unit tests and integration tests on it, and only then deploy it if it was successful. But you shouldn't be checking code into your production branch anyway. All code should be written in a new branch so that when stuff like this happens, it doesn't affect production or even UAT.

Comment: Thanks captain. The server was not responding to pushes on code that had passed all checks on the CI/CD pipeline by any developer for almost 2 weeks. My push was ok to but I did a hurried 2nd push with a logging statement to see if the staging server was running my code.Thanks for your "Your CI/CD pipeline should start out trying to build the code" code though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the fault of DevOps (or whoever is in charge of DevOps) for not enforcing the use of branches and pull requests.

You should never make changes directly on your production or development branches. Each new feature or bugfix should be done in a new branch that branches off of Development so that if something like this happens, the changes can be rejected without affecting the current iteration of the code.

When you feel like you're done with the development work, you can create a pull request that can be reviewed by your senior or even just a random developer from your team and then approved before it gets merged back into development.

UPDATE: if you're using Git, let me suggest also installing Git Flow on your workstation. It standardises the way in which bug fixes and features work and simplifies branch management.

Comment: I should add, a "pull request" doesn't even need to be done in Git. another dev can simply "pull" your branch to their local machine and try to run it and test the feature you were working on. If it does what it was meant to, they can give a thumbs up and someon can merge the changes into the dev branch and from there into production.

Answer (score 1):

githooks is an optional solution for this.
Another option is to apply CI/CD for your project, any failings of code build, es-lint check, unit tests can trigger an alert email for you.
You can discuss with team on for these two options.